# Possible to compile and run scala-akka scripts from command-line without build tools like sbt?

Tags: scala, akka

I am a beginner learning to program in scala-akka and I have had no problems running my scripts on IntelliJ IDE / and 'sbt run'. However, I can't seem to find any resources that teaches me how to manually use scalac and the akka jar dependency to compile and run just from the command-line. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have Scala and Akka installed somewhere under /home/leo/apps/ and Scala binaries are searchable (e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:home/leo/apps/scala-2.11.8/bin`)

Next, let's say you have a Scala main app `Tweets.scala` along with a few supplementary classes packaged in `akkastreams` under /home/leo/myproject/:

```
akkastreams/
  Tweets.scala
  Author.scala
  HashTag.scala
  Message.scala
  ...
```

Here's how you'll compile and run the app:

```
cd /home/leo/myproject/

# Compile all files in package akkastreams:
scalac -cp "/home/leo/apps/akka-2.4.9/lib/akka/*" akkastreams/*.scala

# Run the main app Tweets (object Tweets extends App):
# Note that classpath includes also current subdir '.'
scala -cp "/home/leo/apps/akka-2.4.9/lib/akka/*:." akkastreams.Tweets
```

A few notes:

1. You could include only specific Akka jars instead of all of them.
2. Without dependencies and versioning being managed by `sbt`, you'll need to manually maintain version consistency between Scala's bundled Akka libraries versus Akka's own ones.
3. While it's a good exercise to see how things are done in a crude way, it's obviously unproductive to do this on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks Leo! This is helpful. I've managed to get my scripts working in this crude way. For a beginner like me it does help to see what is lying underneath the hood and not blindly relying on sbt to do everything for me. I've since also learnt how to use the sbt native packaging plugin to package my scala programmes

Comment: It's also worth noting that I initially thought that I only needed the akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar for my simple scripts which only depend on the akka-actor library, but somehow when i compile/run it on the command-line i need to include the full set of jars in the akka distribution in the classpath for it to be working; my guess is that there are more than just the akka-actor jar i need to include in my classpath but (not sure which ones I need) so i just used included the entire akka/* distribution directory in my classpath

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You should perform `scalac` and `scala` with classpath parameter and selected library jar file.

By the way it's still more convenient to use sbt.